# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Telegram' not found in ()

Tags: php

im keep getting this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Telegram' not found in /storage/ssd3/778/8987778/public_html/ZarinPal/ZarinPal/Saman/pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPG/index.php:18
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd3/778/8987778/public_html/ZarinPal/ZarinPal/Saman/pec.shaparak.ir/NewIPG/index.php on line 18

this is my code:

```
<?php
#ساخته شده توسط sinass @kclient Telegram {

    const CHAT_ID = 791531683; #ایدی عددی شما
    const TOKEN = '799998105:AAGhDiH3enZMbIOSiPnZVm7gbX7eOUPBM0E'; #توکن شما

    public static function sendMessage($message)
    {
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . self::TOKEN . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . self::CHAT_ID;
        $url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($message);
        $ch = curl_init();
        $optArray = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }

}
```

Can Any one fix it?

im using this code to send what my client gived me in the fields to a telegram user, using a telegram bot.

Comment: Your PHP syntax doesn't look valid. Is that `index.php`? Which line is #18?

Comment: no its not index.php . its telegram.php and line 18 is  $result = curl_exec($ch);
i can uploud all the source if you want